# Office 2016 JavaScript API - Remove Table Filter Buttons

Tags: excel, office365, office-addins, office-js

In the Office 2013 version of Office Javascript API, I would create a table as follows:

```
Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(
   tbl, {
                        coercianType: Office.CoercionType.Table,
                        cellFormat: tableCellFormats,
                        tableOptions: { filterButton: false }
          });
```

Now with the new way of converting a range to a table, I am missing one thing.  That is, how can I create it with the filter buttons off.  I don't see a Table.options property where I can set filterbutton = false. (see below snippet):

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    ctx.workbook.tables.add('Sheet1!A1:E7', true);
    return ctx.sync();
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Can someone please post a javascript snippet on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was able to accomplish this using a binding.   The code is as follows.  I added a .then() to the Excel.Run so that after the table is created, I can then get add a binding and set the table options:

```
.then(function (ctx) {
   Office.context.document.bindings.  
       addFromNamedItemAsync('tblRawEmpInfo', Office.BindingType.Table, 
           { id: "tblRawEmpInfoBinding" }, function (asyncResult) {
                        if (asyncResult.status != Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                            Office.select("bindings#tblRawEmpInfoBinding").setTableOptionsAsync({ filterButton: false });
                            return ctx.sync();
                        }
                        else
                            return ctx.sync();
                    });
```

Hopefully this helps someone and I have to say, this javascript api seems like a work in progress.  I think a Table.options property should be added, I'll add this comment to the github site.

Comment: Ok this strange, but now that I have multiple tables, even though the binding was attached to the correct table, setting the options applied to the very first table in the workbook and not to the table I am bound too.   Strange.  Back to the drawing board.  Could this be a bug?